# A collection of awesome things regarding lodash functional javascript

Tags: functional-programming, lodash

Where can I find such materials? I'm looking to start writing code with lodash and avoid the repetitive vanila javascript, or do I need to read some js library who use lodash as core to start understanding how to become a lodash ninja :)

Comment: Search engines are designed to index these things.  You should definitely use them to find an answer to your question.  Because they do such a good job at this, questions asking for product links or lists of things are off topic here.

Comment: I recommend you check out [this video from Brian Lonsdorf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA). Then make your own decision about whether underscore/lodash is right for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out code from codepen site using tag lodash:

```
codepen.io/tag/lodash/
```